# Joomla URL Additional Get variable broke SEF URLs

Tags: url, joomla, parameters, sef

I am using Joomla 3, in Menu Item I have created two additional fields called City and County which I manually input the value and its passed as a Get variable to the URL.

In components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.xml I have created these two fields.

```
<field name="City" type="text" default="" label="Enter City ID" description="" size="10" />
<field name="County" type="text" default="" label="Enter County ID" description="" size="10" />
```

For example normal article URL looks like index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22

But when I populate the City and County fields the URL becomes like this index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22&City=4&County=1

However, everything seems to work until SEF URL is enabled. But when I enable the SEF URL these additional city and county parameters are not passed and it breaks the whole site.

I have read somewhere this is to do something with router.php and jroute, I am not a programmer and still learning my ropes. Please can someone let me know how I can tell jroute or jrouter to pass these as parameters, I dont want to loose the SEF URLs.

Or if you have alternative method, I will be very greatfull. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this problem by use ArtioSEF JoomSEF plugin. When I use this plugin all SEF and all get parameters are passed as it should.

Thanks